# Set Layout Params for custom View

Tags: android, layoutparams

In XML I was creating a new Entity of `SwipeDeck` (customView) like this :

```
<com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.SwipeDeck
 android:id="@+id/swipe_deck"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="20dp"
 swipedeck:card_spacing="15dp"
 swipedeck:max_visible="1"
 swipedeck:render_above="true"
 swipedeck:swipe_enabled="true">
```

Now I am trying to programmatically set the x and y position. this works fine:

```
cardStack = (SwipeDeck) findViewById(R.id.swipe_deck);

    cardStack.setX(20);
    cardStack.setY(10+actionBarHeight);
```

When I am trying to set the height and width dynamically, nothing happens:

```
cardStack = (SwipeDeck) findViewById(R.id.swipe_deck);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cardStack.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=500;
    params.width =  screen_width - 40;
    cardStack.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Everything happens in onCreate. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the screen_width? Did you check what's the value of screen_width?

Comment: yep, it doesn't matter though. adding a magical number like 500 pixels doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be declaring "params"'s type with respect to the ViewGroup that contains it.
For example, replace the line

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cardStack.getLayoutParams();
```

with

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = cardStack.getLayoutParams();
```

if your custom view is inside a LinearLayout